# Visual Studio is not triggering the design-time data context of user controls

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, mvvm

I am experiencing a weird behavior.

In 'SomeWidgetView' I've got:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MockViewModels:MockSomeWidgetViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

And in another view, let's call it `View2` I have:

```
<LocalWidgets:SomeWidgetView />
```

I expect that when I open `View2` in Visual Studio designer, the user control (`SomeWidgetView`) design-time data will be loaded. But no. So, seems like Visual Studio only loads the design data of the currently loaded view.

I can do that:

```
<LocalWidgets:SomeWidgetView d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MockViewModels:MockSomeWidgetViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" />
```

and it will be fine in `View2`. But if I have `View1`, which loads `View2`, which loads `SomeWidgetView`, then the design-time data won't be loaded.

Seems like VS only loads design-time data for the currently opened view. Is there any way to force a 'cascade' load of the design data?

Comment: I'd wager the DataContext is flowing from the root of the designer.  Normally, you'd have a Window1 view model, and Window2 (are you actually saying you're embedding a window in a window? Also, no such thing as a widget--would be helpful to refer to the actual underlying types to clear up confusion) is bound to some property of Window1's data context, and your widget is then bound to a property of this view model... and the flow overrides the design time instantiation.

Comment: I have edited the question to clear the confusion about the windows. It's a view within a view. What prevents me from having a `widget` view? It's a view, the underlying type is a View, but in the context of my app it acts as a widget. This doesn't matter - the question is, why doesn't VS look into the definition of the included sub-view and see that it has a `d:DataContext`?

Comment: Because it isn't visual studio, its WPF.  Data contexts flow from the root to all children.  Just because a child has a DataContext defined on it, that doesn't change the behavior.  It really all depends on when the context is set and when the flow is executed.  Setting the DataContext after initialization occurs guarantees overwrite.  But the extension setting the data context in this case happens during deserialization of the XAML.  Looks like it's happening before the DC flows.  Side question: what's a "view"? Use the base class name, not a generic term for a control.

Comment: The DataContext at the root should define the object graph that is used throughout the form.  If you have Root => view A => view B and you want ViewModelB to be the DataContext of view B, then your object graph should be RootViewModel.SomePropertyOfTypeViewModelA.SomePropertyOfTypeViewModelB.  Your bindings should ensure this route is taken in each view.  As long as MockSomeWidgetViewModel can be bound against in this manner, and the constructor creates the necessary object graph, it will work as expected.